# Grails: Load Data while Scrolling Page Down

Tags: javascript, grails, scroll

I want to dynamically load data while Scrolling a GSP Page Down like facebook does.

Is that possible ?

I am using grails 1.3.7
thanks.

Comment: It's about javascript, not grails

Comment: I guess the OP mentioned Grails in case there's a Grails plugin that can help with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detect whether scroller has reached the end of page. If so, just load new piece of information. Something like

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
       loadNewData();
    }
});

function loadNewData(){
    /* add code to fetch new content and add it to the DOM */
}
```

Here is an example on jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QsNCy/

Comment: just added jsfiddle example, is that enough?

Answer (score 2):

You can also refer tag remotePageScroll of [remote-pagination plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/remote-pagination) version 0.3, to load and append more records to the existing list on a click of a button, just like what linkedin does.
Cheers!