# How can I implement dynamic scrolling with ajax / JSF2.2?

Tags: jsf

I have a list of items that I would like to present. I want to ajax load items as the user scrolls down (I have no problem doing this using JS). The problem that I am experiencing is that I can only re-render the whole `ui:repeat` and not just a component that contains `new items`.

Is there an common way to do this? Can I code a bean method that returns only the `<li>` part of the dom and handle the weaving on the client-side? Should I just write a method that returns raw data and then use `JS` to handle rendering?

PS .I am sure this has been asked before, but I can't find the relevant posts

Comment: $("div").animate({scrollTop: $("div").get(0).scrollHeight},100);

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/15910848/1065197

Comment: So basically, I need to create a method that returns a JSON string that I manage VIA JS/JQuery. Is a reason why I should use a RequestBean and not my ViewBean?

Comment: You can make it `@ViewScoped` if you want, but you have to be aware of the impact of the bean scope and manage its resources as well.